# Hosting a primary domain from a folder - Apache rewrite not working as expected

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, url-rewriting

I had been using an Apache rewrite rule to successfully host a domain on shared hosting from a folder inside the account for clarity and cleanliness, so that the domain was in the folder structure at the same level as the subdomains.

So rather than:

```
public_html
  files & folders for main domain 
  subdomain folders
```

I had been using:

```
public_html
  folder containing main domain
  subdomain folders
```

I was using htaccess rewrite rules to allow the setup to work. The rules are from various hosting setup guides online and agree on the structure ([1 of the original sources](https://www.westhost.com/knowledgebase/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=1114233), there are multiple identical sources.), for example:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourmaindomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subfolder/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?yourmaindomain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ subfolder/index.php [L]
```

Unfortunately something changed and now the site works but always redirects me to `http://yourmaindomain.com/subfolder/` instead of serving the site from the folder but not changing the URL. For example a URL typed into the browser bar of `http://yourmaindomain.com/testcategory/testpage.php` would redirect me to `http://yourmaindomain.com/subfolder/testcategory/testpage.php` but still work as normal. Before where I could serve the site from `subfolder` but the browser URL would remain `http://yourmaindomain.com`.

Adding 302 Networking tab data:

```
Request URL:http://yourmaindomain.com/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Moved Temporarily
Remote Address:143.95.77.213:80
Response Headers
view source
Cache-Control:no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:0
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Fri, 23 Sep 2016 20:35:11 GMT
Expires:Wed, 11 Jan 1984 05:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=15
Location:http://yourmaindomain.com/subfolder/wp-admin/install.php
ngpass_ngall:1
Server:nginx
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Host:yourmaindomain.com
Pragma:no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.116 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: @anubhava - I understand that something changed it not easy to diagnose, but didn't think the info helped actually diagnose it as I have reversed the process and it does not restore the functionality... The exact process of what happened was I moved the domain to a differently named subfolder and updated the rewrite to reflect that, that is all. And yes I tried clearing the browser cache (and a completely different computer).

Comment: @anubhava - The rules do redirect, I'm not sure you understand the problem. I posting 302 Network tab data above.

Comment: Though not mentioned in your question but it appears you're using WP. There can be many reasons WP behaving this way e.g. plugins, permalinks etc

Comment: I didn't mention WP because it isn't the cause as this happens without WP! I narrowed the frickin' causes down to the actual useful facts for StackOverflow...

Comment: I was looking to see if someone had input about the rewrites being wrong or something...I guess I am going to move the files back to the root of the account and move on. Thanks

Comment: Your rules appear to be fine. As I wrote above WP is a totally different beast which can cause this behavior due to many reasons. If there is any reproducible problem with plain vanilla code then surely you will get direct answers.

Comment: You haven't noticed that the server answering in that log is not Apache but nginx? `Server:nginx`